# BackgroundWorker - Where does the control go to after work is complete?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a .NET Windows forms application that is to be used for importing a lot of data and doing various calculations on each import. For this purpose, I've created one "main" worker and several "child" workers.

The import jobs are all listed within a MySql database and I've set up a function that checks if job exist or not.

What I need to know is where the control is passed to after the child workers are finished doing their jobs? Do they need to call the main worker again for it to run and assign jobs to the child workers?

The main worker is called upon form load event. So if I run my main worker for the first time and initiate work at child level, will the main worker pass control to the form load again?

I cannot do a test run since my import jobs each cost money (for API usage/hits). So I want to write the app as much as possible before carrying out a test run.

Comment: And you can't write some dummy routing for import for testing?

Comment: Hi Blam. I could, but each of the child workers have their own dedicated connection/account to connect into MySql, table locks, and a lot of stored procedures to call before they can claim that work is finished. I want to test all those in one go if possible to see how it all orchestrates.

Comment: You said you wanted to write the app as much as possible but test runs cost money.

Comment: Yes, that's an API that the app uses (not a free one and without any sandbox) which costs for each import (in my case for each child worker's run). Since this is a financial app (for stock markets), there's over a 100 calculated data fields (e.g. 10 day highest price). If that changes something within the database during a test run, there would be a whole lot of work to do reversing those calculations. Better to post a question and confirm?

Comment: Sounds like you need to improve the design of your API interface code so that you can swap it out for a test component that doesn't hit the pay-for-use API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, once you start the background work, control returns to the calling method while the work gets processed on another thread.

You can create an event handler that notifies you when the background work is completed.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
```

A complete usage example can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx